# can't get @font-face to work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a custom font on my website. On my CSS page I have:

```
body
{
    font-family: HurmeGeometricSans4_SemiBold;
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: HurmeGeometricSans4_SemiBold;
    src: url(resources/Hurme_Design_-_HurmeGeometricSans4_SemiBold.otf);
}
```

The file is initially named "Hurme Design - HurmeGeometricSans4 SemiBold" and I bought it with a web license from myfonts.com. The resources directory is in the same directory that my style sheet sits in. Can anyone see what I'm doing here that might be wrong? Have tried a lot but can't get it to work. This is to be used on mobile safari mainly.

Comment: if it's the same dir, shouldn't you ditch 'resources/' from the URL? To make sure, use the complete `http://` url to see if it works. The CSS looks good to me.

Comment: Have you [come across this](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) yet?

Comment: @Marcel - that worked, want to put it as an answer?

Comment: @CoDEFRo Done, and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the CSS is in the same directory as the font forget about adding the subdirectory, in your case `resources/`.
It will read as `resources/resources/font` instead of the required `resources/font`.

Whenever in doubt, use the complete URL (ex. `http://www.yourdomain.com/path-to-font/font`)

Answer (score 0):

try this

**CSS**

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: myCustomFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

div
{
  font-family:myCustomFont;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>test custom font</div>
```

**UPDATE** : (with an html page and the font in the same directory)

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

@font-face
{
    font-family: myCustomFont;
     src: url(elephant.ttf);
}

div
{
 font-family:myCustomFont;
}

</style>


</head>




<body>

<div>custom font</div>
default font

</body>



</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I tried that, "test custom font" showed up but it looked like the default font.

Comment: I figured it out appreciate you taking the time to write that though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding format hint **format("opentype")** like this:

```
    body
    {
        font-family: HurmeGeometricSans4_SemiBold;
    }

    @font-face
    {
        font-family: HurmeGeometricSans4_SemiBold;
        src: url(resources/Hurme_Design_-_HurmeGeometricSans4_SemiBold.otf) format("opentype");
    }
```

Also, the @font-face has some browser issues - you can check a browser comaptibility chart e.g. here: http://everythingfonts.com/font-face#idTab3

You may also use an online font converter and have the font converted to multiple formats and use the generated css.

Comment: Thanks for response, I ended up just having to put the full URL for the path.